# Counting friends from two columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have two columns with users ids and their friends but the same user can appear in another column and the rows are unique. For example,

```
1 5
2 6
2 8
2 7
3 2
```

So to count all friends of user 2 I need to count three from col2 and one from col1.

I found a solution to do this with one column. (I need to count this for all users)

```
SELECT col1, COUNT(*)
FROM friends
GROUP BY col1
```

If I add

```
UNION 
SELECT col2, COUNT(*)
FROM friends
GROUP BY col2
```

It just adds rows below, although the count in both cases is valid.
For user 2 it would be

> 3
>
> 1

But I need one value which is the sum of both:

> 4

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your union query as a subquery, and then group and sum over the user at the top level of your query:

```
SELECT user, SUM(friends) AS friends
FROM (
  SELECT col1 AS user, COUNT(*) AS friends
  FROM friends
  GROUP BY col1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col2, COUNT(*)
  FROM friends
  GROUP BY col2
) f
GROUP BY user
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
user    friends
1       1
2       4
3       1
5       1
6       1
7       1
8       1
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9qnyU7CvUcQVS3Zj9h6HuV/0)